Get the proper diff for a pull request from Git
A couple of months ago, I made a pull request on the GitHub repository for the project I'm using in my program.
I have been working with this PR and now it looks like the easiest way to move forward is recreate it cleanly.
In order to do that I need to find a commit I started from to run the git diff on the local repo.
Is there an easy way to find a commit SHA a couple months before the known one? Or I will have to run git log and just inspect it visually until I see the commit I started with?


In order to do that I need to find a commit I started from to run the git diff on the local repo.

You don’t need to find it manually, though – Git will find a common ancestor for you if you use the a...b form of git diff. If you branched off “main” and you’re on your change branch,
git diff main...


This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both <commit>. git diff A...B is equivalent to git diff $(git merge-base A B) B. You can omit any one of <commit>, which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.


I'm not sure what main is. Did you mean to say git diff master?

@Igor: I said ‘if you branched off “main”’. If you branched off “master”, then yes, it’s git diff master....
